# Remove Specific "Store View" settings for products

Tags: product, sql, default

While setting up a CSV to import products through Magmi, instead of putting "admin" in the "store" column, I put the name of a "store view."

This in turn has now set unchecked the "use default" and put duplicate entries in the store view for those product. This is becoming an issue when disabling products through import, updating prices, etc..

Is there any way through PHP/SQL to programmatically remove these custom settings for a store view, while limiting the products it is affecting? I have the same prefix on all SKUs affected, and some have already been "cured."

EDIT: THIS ANSWER WORKED FOR ME

```
<?php

include 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app();

/** store id for which you would like to KEEP values */
$defaultStoreId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $model */
$model        = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$resource     = $model->getResource();
$entityType   = $resource->getEntityType();
$entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();
$adapter      = $resource->getWriteConnection();

/** gather the names of all tables that contain the attribute values to be removed */
$tables = array();

/** get all attribute value tables, making sure to leave out catalog_product_entity */
$attributes = $entityType->getAttributeCollection();
$attributes->addFieldToFilter('backend_type', array('neq' => 'static'));
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute $attribute */
    $tables[] = $attribute->getBackendTable();
}
$tables = array_unique($tables);

/** get product ids of all products whose SKU begins with 16- */
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => '16-%'));
$productIds = $collection->getAllIds();

$valuesDeletedCount = 0;
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $condition = array(
        'entity_type_id = ?' => $entityTypeId, // here we ensure that we are only dealing with values belonging to PRODUCTS
        'entity_id IN(?)'    => $productIds, // here we make sure that we are only dealing with SKUs beginning with 16-
        'store_id != ?'      => $defaultStoreId, // here we make sure we are deleting from ALL stores except for DEFAULT
    );
    $valuesDeletedCount += $adapter->delete($table, $condition);
}
echo $valuesDeletedCount . ' non-default attribute values deleted.';

?>
```

saved as "reset_defaults.php" in my "/magento" directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more programattic method. It still skirts Magento's save() methods and the beforeSave/afterSave events but this works great and I use it sometimes in development to reset product data.

```
<?php 

    /** store id from which you would like to remove values */
    $storeId = 1;

    /** example attribute codes that you would to remove values for */
    $attributeCodesToReset = array('name', 'description');

    $model        = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $resource     = $model->getResource();
    $entityTypeId = $resource->getEntityType()->getEntityTypeId();
    $adapter      = $resource->getWriteConnection();

    /** use collection(filter it appropriately) to grab product ids */
    $collection = $model->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 886);
    $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
    $productIds = $collection->getAllIds();

    foreach($attributeCodesToReset as $attributeCode) {
        $attribute = $resource->getAttribute($attributeCode);
        $condition = array(
            'entity_id IN(?)'    => $productIds,
            'attribute_id = ?'   => $attribute->getId(),
            'store_id = ?'       => $storeId,
            'entity_type_id = ?' => $entityTypeId
        );
        $adapter->delete($attribute->getBackendTable(), $condition);
    }
```

**Update**

This is how you would delete all attribute values from ALL NON-DEFAULT stores for products whose SKU begins with '16-'

```
/** store id for which you would like to KEEP values */
$defaultStoreId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $model */
$model        = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$resource     = $model->getResource();
$entityType   = $resource->getEntityType();
$entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();
$adapter      = $resource->getWriteConnection();

/** gather the names of all tables that contain the attribute values to be removed */
$tables = array();

/** get all attribute value tables, making sure to leave out catalog_product_entity */
$attributes = $entityType->getAttributeCollection();
$attributes->addFieldToFilter('backend_type', array('neq' => 'static'));
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute $attribute */
    $tables[] = $attribute->getBackendTable();
}
$tables = array_unique($tables);

/** get product ids of all products whose SKU begins with 16- */
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => '16-%'));
$productIds = $collection->getAllIds();

$valuesDeletedCount = 0;
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $condition = array(
        'entity_type_id = ?' => $entityTypeId, // here we ensure that we are only dealing with values belonging to PRODUCTS
        'entity_id IN(?)'    => $productIds, // here we make sure that we are only dealing with SKUs beginning with 16-
        'store_id != ?'      => $defaultStoreId, // here we make sure we are deleting from ALL stores except for DEFAULT
    );
    $valuesDeletedCount += $adapter->delete($table, $condition);
}
echo $valuesDeletedCount . ' non-default attribute values deleted.';
```

Comment: @StevenDJackson  if my answer worked for you or got you going in the right direction, please accept it so that I may get my reputation points, its been a while. Thanks :-)

Comment: I assume I would need to add my specific attributes to the $attributeCodesToReset array - but there are a lot of them. I'd like to just reset all values per specific store view and only keep the admin original

Comment: @StevendJackson Yes, that is exactly right. Also, for the `$storeId` variable, just change that value to the ID of whatever store you want to remove the values for. I should also mention that `$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 886);` is just an example filter for the collection.  Do you want to do this for all products or a specific set of products?

Comment: Yes, I have a particular set of SKUs I need this to apply to: All SKUs beginning with "16-" need to have all "per store/non default" entries removed so that it always goes to using the Default

Comment: @StevendJackson Answer updated. Based on the criteria you gave me, you can just copy, paste, run and problem solved in about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @StevendJackson If my answer worked, which I am sure it did, please go ahead and mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: sorry for the delay, yes this fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: my pleasure, glad i could help :-)

Comment: Tried running this in my staging area (exact duplicate of the production store) and got this error: - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$defaultStoreId' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/tugasunw/public_html/16_updates.php on line 4

Comment: That usually means there is a bracket or semicolon missing somewhere. Can you post the full contents of the file?

Comment: I copy/paste your lower edit between a "<? php" at the top of the file and a "?>" at the bottom of the file

Comment: The opening php tag should be `<?php`, not `<? php`. Other than that, i just copied and pasted the code into a php file and errors.

Comment: I have fixed the `<?php` error at the top of the file but still get this error: `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' not found in /home/tugasunw/staging/16_updates.php on line 4`

Comment: It looks like you are using an external file, not part of any module. In that case, place this just after the opening php tag and before any of the code starts. `include 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app();`

Comment: That fixed it. I now got the result "8979 non-default attribute values deleted."

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but now with category changes that were made a store view level instead of the admin/global view level.

Comment: Thanks again for this! Had to remove some non-default changes when someone here forgot to add a "store" column to their import sheets

Answer (score 3):

This is best done with a few SQL queries (don't forget to make a backup before!)

Let's say your store view has the ID 1 (if you don't know the ID, you can look it up in the `core_store` table) and the SKU prefix is `p_`

Then you have to remove all rows from the attribute tables with `store_id=1` and `entity_id IN ( [product ids where sku starts with "p_" ])`.

For `varchar` attributes, the query is

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar 
    WHERE store_id=1
    AND entity_id IN (
        SELECT * from catalog_product_entity WHERE sku LIKE "p\_%"
    );
```

Do the same for the other `catalog_product_entity_*` attribute tables.